# Google tag manager v4 tracking screenView issue android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using this GTM utils function to push screen event, and I am sending Screen Name as a second paramater

```
public static void pushOpenScreenEvent(Context context, String screenName) {
        //ContainerHolderSingleton.getContainerHolder().refresh();
        DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
        dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", screenName));
}
```

And calling this function in activity like this

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
          GtmUtils.pushOpenScreenEvent(this, "Contactus_tagmanager");
}
```

But in google analytics panel I get openScreen(event) view instead of Contactus_tagmanager screen name.

Can anybody please tell where am I making mistake?

Thanks

Comment: What's the implementation of `GtmUtils.pushOpenScreenEvent()`?

Comment: @hidro I've shared its implementation above.

Comment: In GTM you would need a tag to to wire up 'openScreen' events, and send 'screenName' to GA. Otherwise, you can use automatic screen tracking feature of GA.

Comment: I have created openScreen trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you created dataLayer type variable (screenName) in tag manager panel? I guess this is the problem, you are trying to map wrong type variable. screenName variable must be dataLayer type.

[image]